# My Tablet PC has a jog dial (typically used for scrolling up and down) but it does not work by default in Ubuntu 9.10 -- how can I make it work?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, tablet, key-binding

I have an HP Compaq TC4400 and I recently was able to make most of the Tablet PC functions work in Ubuntu 9.10. (The step-by-step guide can be found in [my blog](http://thirdworldpc.blogspot.com/2010/03/hp-compaq-tc4400-and-ubuntu-910-karmic.html).) Unfortunately I have yet to make the jog dial work. This would be particularly useful for scrolling up and down websites and documents when the TC4400 is in slate mode (with no access to the keyboard).

I would be much obliged if anybody could tell me:

1. How to find out the input button/key assignment that Ubuntu 9.10 has for jog-up and jog-down;
2. How to assign jog-up to scroll up (D-pad key UP, or PAGE UP) and jog-down to scroll down (D-Pad key DOWN, or PAGE DOWN).

I am using *xbindkeys* to assign different shortcuts to the quick launch buttons, perhaps I could use the same program for the jog dial? I would have done that, except I do not know how to find the proper button/key assignment for *xbindkeys* to use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `xev` in a terminal window. If the jog wheel is detected, an event should show up.

Comment: I just tried this and nothing registered in the terminal. Does that mean that setting up the jog wheel would be too complicated?

Comment: Movement of the wheel is not detected as an X event--which means it's not set up as a key.

There might be some information scattered about the internet, but my guess right now is "no, it's not going to work"

Answer (score 0):

This blog allowed me to use the jog wheel with 11.04. Not totally sure how she figured it out. http://alice-at-ubuntu.blogspot.com/2010/10/i-want-scroller-back.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.